# How do I change the appearance of my Xcode app?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to create a dark mode for my application made in Xcode 8. My first though was to use Mojave's Dark Aqua, but I get many errors:

`Unrecognized effect parameter type 10 encountered for effect type 1131375730. Skipping.`

My next idea was to create my own .car file, using https://github.com/insidegui/AppearanceMaker. However, this did not change the background/window, even when I edited its `Windows and Menus/Menu/Menu Background` *and* its `Colors/Window Background`.

My *third* idea was to use El Capitan's Dark Theme (for the dark Menu and Dock, I'd assume). However, this changed the Aqua blue to a grey. Laaaaame.

What am I to do?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, Mojave's `DarkAquaAppearance worked`! I needed to set my NS*Window* to the theme. (using `yourNSWindow.appearance = [[NSAppearance alloc] initWithAppearanceNamed:@"DarkAquaAppearance" bundle:nil];`, making sure that DarkAquaAppearance.car is in your "Supporting Files")

If you want to do the same, I have all the Mojave appearances in https://github.com/radzo73/Mojave-Appearances. It still will call errors about "Unrecognized effect parameter", but that's probably just the compressed assets, and I'm using an older system. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

With (real) hope,
Conrad